Java OpenAI API PDF Extraction Format Issue
Im trying to use OpenAI Api to read the content of a Pdf but when i send the message with the pdf attached im getting this error:
"Here is the full translation, including the JSON:
"I was unable to find all the necessary data due to the format of the text extracted from the PDF. Below is the JSON with partial information:
{
    "File": "file-BfjXxlvbiu1L0gMDgohyZya1",
    "Business Name": "",
    "Settlement Period": "",
    "Contribution Account Code": "Incorrect format"
}

If you can provide more details about the structure of the PDF file or specific texts that contain this data, I will try to extract the information more accurately."
All I just did was to create an Assistant, save a pdf in files, create a thread, create a message with the file id as attachtment, run the message and get the result.
This is my code (In Java) (Some parts are in spanish):
The Assistant code:
public static void createAssistant(String nameAssis, String descAssis, String instAssis) {
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();

        String jsonBody = String.format(
                "{"
                    + "\"name\": \"%s\","
                    + "\"description\": \"%s\","
                    + "\"instructions\": \"%s\","
                    + "\"model\": \"%s\","
                    + "\"tools\": [{\"type\": \"code_interpreter\"}]"
                + "}",
                nameAssis, descAssis, instAssis, Configuration.MODELO
            );

        System.out.println(jsonBody);
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create(Configuration.ASSISTANT_URL))
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + Configuration.API_KEY).header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .header("OpenAI-Beta", "assistants=v2").POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(jsonBody)).build();

        HttpResponse<String> response;
        try {
            response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

            System.out.println("Response: " + response.body());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

Then the file code:
public static void uploadFile(String filePath) {
        try {
            // File and client setup
            File file = new File(filePath);
            System.out.println("-> " + file.getAbsolutePath() + " || " + file.exists());
            
            if (!file.exists()) {
                System.err.println("File not found: " + filePath);
                return;
            }

            HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();

            // Build the multipart form data body
            String boundary = "----WebKitFormBoundary" + System.currentTimeMillis();
            String fileName = file.getName();

            // Multipart body content
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            // Add purpose part
            sb.append("--").append(boundary).append("\r\n");
            sb.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"purpose\"\r\n\r\n");
            sb.append("assistants\r\n");

            // Add file part
            sb.append("--").append(boundary).append("\r\n");
            sb.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"")
              .append(fileName).append("\"\r\n");
            sb.append("Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n");

            // Convert to byte array
            byte[] fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
            byte[] bodyBytes = sb.toString().getBytes();

            // Combine text and file parts
            byte[] multipartBody = new byte[bodyBytes.length + fileBytes.length + ("--" + boundary + "--\r\n").getBytes().length];
            System.arraycopy(bodyBytes, 0, multipartBody, 0, bodyBytes.length);
            System.arraycopy(fileBytes, 0, multipartBody, bodyBytes.length, fileBytes.length);
            System.arraycopy(("--" + boundary + "--\r\n").getBytes(), 0, multipartBody, bodyBytes.length + fileBytes.length, ("--" + boundary + "--\r\n").getBytes().length);

            // Create the HTTP request
            HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                    .uri(URI.create(Configuration.FILE_URL))
                    .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + Configuration.API_KEY)
                    .header("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary)
                    .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofByteArray(multipartBody))
                    .build();

            // Send the request and get the response
            HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
            System.out.println("Response: " + response.body());
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

After that the thread code:
public static void createThread(String idAssis) {
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();

        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create("https://api.openai.com/v1/threads"))
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + Configuration.API_KEY).header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .header("OpenAI-Beta", "assistants=v2").POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.noBody()).build();

        HttpResponse<String> response;
        try {
            response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

            System.out.println("Response: " + response.body());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }

The message:
public static void crearMensaje(String idThread, String idFile) {
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();

        String jsonBody = String.format(
                "{"
                + "\"role\":\"user\", "
                + "\"content\":\"Lee el PDF adjunto y extrea datos.\", "
                + "\"attachments\": ["
                + "{\"file_id\": \"%s\", "
                + "\"tools\": ["
                + "{"
                + "\"type\": \"code_interpreter\" "
                + "}"
                + "]}]"
                + "}", idFile);

        System.out.println(jsonBody);
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create("https://api.openai.com/v1/threads/" + idThread +"/messages"))
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + Configuration.API_KEY).header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .header("OpenAI-Beta", "assistants=v2").POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(jsonBody)).build();

        HttpResponse<String> response;
        try {
            response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

            System.out.println("Response: " + response.body());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }

And the run of the message
public static void ejectutarMensaje(String idThread, String idAssis) {
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();

        String jsonBody = String.format(
                "{"
                        + "\"assistant_id\": \"%s\""
                        + "}", idAssis);

        System.out.println(jsonBody);
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create("https://api.openai.com/v1/threads/" + idThread + "/runs"))
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + Configuration.API_KEY).header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .header("OpenAI-Beta", "assistants=v2").POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(jsonBody)).build();

        HttpResponse<String> response;
        try {
            response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

            System.out.println("Response: " + response.body());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }

Finally reading the message result:
public static void getResultadoMensaje(String idThread, String idRun) {
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();

        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create("https://api.openai.com/v1/threads/" + idThread +"/messages?run_id=" + idRun))
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + Configuration.API_KEY).header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .header("OpenAI-Beta", "assistants=v2").GET().build();

        HttpResponse<String> response;
        try {
            response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

            System.out.println("Response: " + response.body());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }

